# Multiple Point Selection in multiple series in Shinobi

Tags: shinobi

I have two line series and how do I make points on both series selected at the same time? Basically, my chart has 2 y values sharing the same x value and I'm representing them as two series. I want to display both points as selected for a given X Value.

Hi there,Thanks for the reply. 
I'm doing that in

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart toggledSelectionForPoint:(SChartDataPoint *)dataPoint inSeries:(SChartSeries *)series atPixelCoordinate:(CGPoint)pixelPoint

    SChartDataPoint* point1Series1 = [chart.datasource sChart:chart dataPointAtIndex:dataPoint.index forSeriesAtIndex:0];
    point1Series1.selected = YES;

    SChartDataPoint* point1Series2 = [chart.datasource sChart:chart dataPointAtIndex:dataPoint.index forSeriesAtIndex:1];
    point1Series2.selected = YES;
```

When I print the selected state of both points after this line of code, they return 1(selected) but they don't seem to appear as selected on the chart only the one I selected on the chart on device seem to appear as selected though I'm calling redrawChart after that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's likely (and I'm guessing because I can't see your code) that your chart data source isn't returning a reference to a datapoint which is part of the chart, but instead generating a new datapoint object each time you request one.

In order to cope with this you can request the data points from the chart itself, via the `dataSeries` property on `SChartSeries` objects.

The following delegate method should perform the selection you require.

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart toggledSelectionForPoint:(SChartDataPoint *)dataPoint inSeries:(SChartSeries *)series atPixelCoordinate:(CGPoint)pixelPoint
{
    // Selection details
    NSInteger dataPointIndex = dataPoint.index;
    BOOL selected = dataPoint.selected;

    for (SChartSeries *chartSeries in chart.series) {
        // If only one data point in the series can be selected at once, then deselect the rest
        if(!series.togglePointSelection && selected) {
            for(SChartDataPoint *dp in chartSeries.dataSeries.dataPoints) {
                dp.selected = NO;
            }
        }
        // Find the data point and perform the selection
        SChartDataPoint *dp = chartSeries.dataSeries.dataPoints[dataPointIndex];
        dp.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just got this working on Friday exactly the same way as here. Thanks Sammy.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set .selected on the datapoints and customise the series.style.selectedPointStyle properties to display points how you wish :)

Comment: Please refer to my original question. I edited the question to give you more context.